# How can I casting Interface from COM class

Tags: c#, com

I registered the C# made dll in COM. (I used regasm.exe and strong name +gacutil.exe)

This is the code that I registered with COM.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("45063BA7-237A-43B1-B799-7B000FFE7B78")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IMyCOMAPI
{
    void TestMethod();
}



[Guid("41EFFD90-9D94-4884-A8CC-9567B86FB79F")]    
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("MyCOMAPI")]  
public class MyCOMAPI : IMyCOMAPI
{
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("COM method call");
    }
}
```

And I want to use COM the other project like this

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("45063BA7-237A-43B1-B799-7B000FFE7B78")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface IMyCOMAPI
{
    void TestMethod();
}


public class Test
{
    public void TestCreate()
    {

        Guid Class_guid = new Guid("41EFFD90-9D94-4884-A8CC-9567B86FB79F");
        Type Classtype = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Class_guid);

        object comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(Classtype);


        IMyCOMAPI simple = comObject as IMyCOMAPI;

        if (simple != null)
        {
            simple.TestMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code didn't cast the interface.
I already know invoke using methodinfo, but I am looking for a way to make it easier to use through the interface.

Comment: You managed to squeeze no less then four Very Bad Practices in one question, one more you didn't mention.  That's too much to stick a fork into, just add a reference to the .NET assembly so you can write `new MyCOMAPI()`.

Comment: The .NET COM interop system isn't stupid. It's not designed to wrap a Runtime Callable Wrapper around a COM Callable Wrapper around a managed object. COM interop is all designed around *one side or the other* not being managed code.